# How to move/delete a file (on the user filesystem) in Flash or Flex?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

In need to move/delete files on the local file system of the user from a web page.

I know the flash player run all applications in a sandbox for security reasons.
But maybe is there the possibility for the user to allow local filesystem operations (in some advanced settings). Or maybe to sign/join a certificate.

PS : The Air platform is not a possible way for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is strictly impossible. Use a Java applet or AIR.

Comment: +!; if the browser could access the local machine enough to delete files, it sounds like it'd be a serious security issue.  Just imagine the malware we'd have.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an intranet application and you are not worried about the security concerns (knowing your users thoroughly), you could achieve it by adding the url to trusted sites and lower the browser security settings in each of your client browser (as pre-requisite) and have the browser allow scripts across domains. Using ActiveX, you can execute dos command lines to perform file operations. Flex invokes these operations through JavaScript (external interface).

Answer (score 0):

Can't help but ask OP a simple question: Would you feel comfortable if a stranger had access/right to shuffle you machine's file system?
FTQuest